# How to reject blank before_save callback rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-5.2

i want to reject blank param with model callback

Schema:
Interviews

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| note           | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| interview_at   | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at     | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at     | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Controller:

```
  def interviews
    return [] unless params[:interviews]
    parse_params(:interviews).map do |interview|
      Interview.find_or_initialize_by( interview }) )
    end
  end
```

Model:

```
class Interview < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :remove_blank

  def remove_blank
    @new_record = false if interview_at.blank?
  end
end
```

Example:

Input:

> 1. Interview 1( interview_at: '2019-09-15 22:00', note: 'abc')
> 2. Interview 2( interview_at: '', note: 'bcd')

Output:

> 1. Interview 1( interview_at: 2019-09-15 22:00, note: 'abc')
> 2. Interview 2( interview_at: 2019-09-15 22:00, note: 'abc')

before_save return wrong attribute when i create. How can i fix that?

Thank you for help

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. Your callback is called `remove_blank` but it does not remove anything, it sets a variable ´@new_record` to false. What do you do with that variable?

Comment: What RDBMS (database) are you using?

Comment: - i expect it will not create and reject create if interview_at is nil
- I'm using mysql

Comment: `validates :interviewed_at, presence: true` It won't create the record if that attribute is not present

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try, you would want to create a validation, this will prevent the record from being saved and make the model record will return false when you call `valid?` on it.

```
class Interview < ApplicationRecord
  validate :interview_at_not_blank

  def interview_at_not_blank
    errors.add(:interview_at, :blank, message: "cannot be blank") unless interview_at.blank?
  end
end
```